# superceded patch - would the old one still show?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, patch-management

Example - if you have a Windows security patch that was released earlier in the year and you installed it. Then, if another security patch came out to SUPERCEDE that original one...would the server/computer show both patches as being installed or just the latest one?

I imagine it would be both...?

Thanks,

Comment: "Shown" where?  Add/Remove Programs control panel?

Comment: Yes, Control panel or via powershell command (get-hotfix)..

Comment: Usually both.  There may be some oddball exceptions.